# How to overide a due date in Workflow task?

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1

In the online documentation, it states:

> To set, or to allow users to set, a time constraint on this Activity, select options in the lower half of the dialog:  **Allow to override due date** 
>    If selected, this option enables users to do one of the following:
>  
>   •If no period is specified under Expires in, the user can set a due date for the specific Activity Instance.
>  
>   •If a period is specified, the user can change the due date of the Activity Instance.
>
> Which Activity Definition a user can modify, and when, depends on the user's rights:
>  
>   •A user with Workflow Management rights can set or change the due date of any Activity at any time (provided that this option is selected for that Activity).
>   •A user with no Workflow Management rights can only set or change the due date when they finish an Activity, and can then only do so for the next Activity or Activities (provided that this option is selected for the Activity they wish to modify).

This is all well and good, but how/where do I make this change? Does this allow me to change the due date through code? **Or** is there a place in the interface where I can change it?

*My understanding:*
When the Workflow task starts, the documentation sounds like the user can change the due date during the Workflow itself, not just from the Visio designer screens. "A user with no Workflow Management rights can only set or change the due date when they finish an Activity, and can then only do so for the next Activity or Activities".

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it right in the Activity definition dialog in Visio?

Comment: Maybe i am misreading the documentation, I will add a senario to the question.

Comment: I believe you need to check `Allow to override due date` and enter the actual expiration script for a given activity. After saving/updating the Workflow Process definition, authorized authors should get the option to change it in the interface per the documentation. Did you update the Process Definition?

Comment: @AlvinReyes: Yes, I have made that selection and saved the definition, but I do not see where the user can change the date in the interface.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. I know the date option was added just on the API side for 2013 GA and it should be available in 2013 SP1 in the UI. Unless you're on GA maybe it isn't available (yet?). If you post your expiration snippet, I can try on one of our environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revived a response from SDL support:

> Hello, thank you for contacting SDL support.
>
> It's not currently possible to change the DueDate property in the
>   Content Manager Explorer interface.  This is only possible via the
>   API.
>
> Best regards, Ian Constable | Senior Support Engineer | SDL

I have asked them to make the online documentation a little bit clearer (maybe just for me) and I will just find a way to set the due date through a Component field and pass it to the Workflow.

Thanks all!

Comment: You could consider a GUI extension/Alchemy plugin